# File Upload not Working in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to PHP and am trying to create a page to upload a jpeg file. The webpage seems to run fine and it appears the file is uploading, however the file is not appearing on the server. Any help you can provide will be great.

The PHP code is:

```
<?php
    $target_dir="/var/www/html/";
    $fileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $target_file=$target_dir . basename($fileName);
    $imageFileType=pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileTempName=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $fileSize=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $fileError=$_FILES["file"]["error"];
    if(($fileType=="image/jpeg")&&($fileSize<100000)){
            if($fileError>0){
                    echo "Return Code: " . $fileError . "<br />";
            }
            else{
                    echo "Upload: " .$fileName . "<br />";
                    echo "Type: " . $fileType . "<br />";
                    echo "Size: " . ($fileSize / 1024) . " kb<br />";
                    echo "Temp file: " . $fileTempName . "<br />";
            if (file_exists($fileName)){
                    unlink($fileName);
            }
            move_uploaded_file($fileTempName,$target_file);
            echo "<br><br>File Temp Name: " .$fileTempName."\r\n <br>";
            echo "Uploaded file stored as : " .$target_file ."<br><br>";
            }       
    }
    else{
            echo "File is not a JPEG or too big.";
    }
?>
```

And the HTML code is as follows:

```
 <html>
       <body>
       <form action="save2web.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label for="file">Filename:</label>
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
       <br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Any errors or other stuff that might be useful for us?

Comment: No errors or comments show up at all. In fact on the web page it all appears normal:

Comment: The web page shows:                                            Upload: screen568x568.jpeg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 25.4140625 kb
Temp file: /tmp/phpYjEfFQ

File Temp Name: /tmp/phpYjEfFQ 
Uploaded file stored as : /var/www/html/screen568x568.jpeg

Comment: Wrap the `move_uploaded_file()` in an `if()` to check if it really has been uploaded. Could be something like file permissions

Comment: I think you intended to check and unlink $target_file rather than $fileName

Comment: Hi Kingkero.  You mean something like this (nothing seems to change):                if(move_uploaded_file($fileTempName,$target_file)){
echo "<br><br>File Temp Name: " .$fileTempName."\r\n <br>";
echo "Uploaded file stored as : " .$target_file ."<br><br>";
}

Comment: @avtar Correct. You still see the success message after the upload?

Comment: @kingkero no now the final two comments don't show up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your server is linux from the path, you may need to change the permissions of the folder your trying to upload to, try changing the folder owner to www-data, this fixed the same issue for me.

Comment: I tried following some instructions on the web to do this, and seemed to upload one file, so thought it solved the problem. However, the same issue has started again. Could you provide some instructions on how you changed the permissions?

Comment: Philip Clegg, that's OK I managed to change the permission - you were right. Once I did that the files uploaded without a problem.

Comment: @bad_boy thanks for pointing that out - still learning the ropes of this forum. Also thanks for your insights on tracking the errors as I built that in too now to ensure everything is working during upload.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, you don't check the returned value of `move_uploaded_file()` at all. But looks like, you're running your script on the **host**, and since most host disallow relative paths, you'd better provide an absolute.

So try, replacing:

```
$target_dir = "/var/www/html/"; // <- This is relative, which might be blocked due to security reasons
```

with

```
$target_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/var/www/html/"; // dirname(__FILE__) is a path to root
```

And then, make sure that the file was uploaded:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file(...)) {
  // error
}
```

Comment: I have made changes as you suggested, however same issue... But with the error check I can see now that the file is not being uploaded.

Comment: try to `var_dump(is_dir($target_dir))` and `var_dump(is_file($target_file))`... what do they say?

Comment: target_dir = true  and target_file=false

Answer (score 0):

Change your target directory like this. Add a .(dot) before the directory name.

```
$target_directory = './var/www/html';
```

Comment: If savetoweb.php file and the var folder are on the same directory so this could be worked because a single .(dot) start with the current directory where the script is placed and executing.